# Filevault Decryption process : Kernel Panic - Method to kill decryption process?

Tags: macos, mojave, encryption, filevault, kernel-panic

I've been trying for two months to update my mac to Catalina, and last night on a suggestion, I disabled FileVault. All was going good and suddenly kernel panic. My mac keeps kernel panicking while trying to decrypt the FileVault, and I cannot seem to find a way to stop this.

One solution I have attempted was to removed my MagSafe, and thereby the decryption is stopped,

As soon as I connect the MagSafe back, the decryption restarts and crashes my mac.

I wanted to know if possible a method to kill this process entirely and go back to where it was. I can't seem to find a straight forward answer online, so I'm trying to ask here.

No, I have not created a time machine back up. No, I do not have another backup somewhere.

Specs: Macbook Air 2015 running Mojave 10.14.6

Crash log:

```
Mon Dec 30 16:46:36 2019

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 2 caller 0xffffff7f95934531): "can not write an object for a fs that is encrypted and locked! (apfs 0xffffff807e377000 o 0xffffff801fc8d9b0)\n"@/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/apfs/apfs-945.275.7/nx/obj.c:4083
Backtrace (CPU 2), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff90b059b9b0 : 0xffffff80143ae6ed 
0xffffff90b059ba00 : 0xffffff80144ea185 
0xffffff90b059ba40 : 0xffffff80144db8ba 
0xffffff90b059bab0 : 0xffffff801435bb40 
0xffffff90b059bad0 : 0xffffff80143ae107 
0xffffff90b059bbf0 : 0xffffff80143adf53 
0xffffff90b059bc60 : 0xffffff7f95934531 
0xffffff90b059bcf0 : 0xffffff7f95934250 
0xffffff90b059bdd0 : 0xffffff7f95933a25 
0xffffff90b059be40 : 0xffffff7f95949b09 
0xffffff90b059bf50 : 0xffffff7f959499c3 
0xffffff90b059bfa0 : 0xffffff801435b0ce 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.filesystems.apfs(945.275.7)[ACFDCC84-EBFD-376E-8361-B16CC6CAF740]@0xffffff7f95887000->0xffffff7f95988fff
            dependency: com.apple.kec.corecrypto(1.0)[16D0DE4A-4774-32C4-B05D-D35601D9FC39]@0xffffff7f953d9000
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleEffaceableStorage(1.0)[10658FF3-EB34-3240-9E63-3FB47B9700FF]@0xffffff7f957f8000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily(2.1)[71BB22B0-3075-35A1-B04E-FBAC574DA80D]@0xffffff7f95302000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
18G103

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 18.7.0: Tue Aug 20 16:57:14 PDT 2019; root:xnu-4903.271.2~2/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: C41337A1-0EC3-3896-A954-A1F85E849D53
Kernel slide:     0x0000000014000000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8014200000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8014100000
System model name: MacBookAir7,2 (Mac-937CB26E2E02BB01)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 39857853318
last loaded kext at 1887025481: com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 6.0.14d3 (addr 0xffffff7f9637b000, size 49152)
loaded kexts:
com.razer.common.razerhid   21.94
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  408.250.3
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBStorageCoexistentDriver    456.260.3
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader 456.260.3
com.apple.driver.AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver 138.4
com.apple.driver.AppleFileSystemDriver  3.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleVirtIO    2.1.3
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.kext  407.200.4
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 40
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.AppleSystemPolicy 1.0
com.apple.filesystems.apfs  945.275.7
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  329.260.5
com.apple.private.KextAudit 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   201
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 6.0.14d3
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   6.0.14d3
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerTransport  6.0.14d3
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHub    1.2
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass   4.0.4
com.apple.driver.usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  900.4.2
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc    5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.networking 5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleHSBluetoothDriver 138.4
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver   6.0.14d3
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   6.0.14d3
com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver  2450.1
com.apple.driver.AppleInputDeviceSupport    2440.2
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard   208
com.apple.driver.AppleHSSPIHIDDriver    55.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext    1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   900.4.2
com.apple.driver.AppleXsanScheme    3
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  301.270.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    288
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    5.6.9
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    5.6.9
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.1.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    4.7.9
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 6.8.6
com.apple.driver.AppleHSSPISupport  55.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostPacketFilter   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 900.4.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssSpiController    3.0.60
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIPCI    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI   1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssDmac 3.0.60
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssGspi 3.0.60
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssI2C  3.0.60
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 493.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleEffaceableStorage 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTDM    456.260.3
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageDriver  145.200.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   408.250.3
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   408.250.3
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.kext.CoreTrust    1
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.KernelRelayHost    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBCommon 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBusPowerController    1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSEPManager    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.IOSlaveProcessor   1
com.apple.iokit.IOTimeSyncFamily    740.2
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.4
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  47
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
```

Comment: What problem was causing an update to take two months? Decryption by itself should not cause a kernel panic. Can you post the KP log here?

Comment: @benwiggy Heres a snippet of the kp https://i.gyazo.com/c2cda54ec67db9e6840b8cd00c842336.png

The update was blocked due to the error when installing : cannot verify storage
(-67916)

I was asuming that updating to the latest beta software and updating catalina would fix it. I updated to the beta sw but cant update catalina. 

I am dependent on Xcode so i need catalina to use SwiftUI

Comment: Would be useful to see the whole thing as a .txt. But also can you explain what problems you've had trying to update to Catalina? And... backup now! If you've got some problem with your file system, then you could lose the lot!

Comment: @benwiggy
cannot verify storage (-67916)

Installlation stops after around 10 minutes and throws this error and quits. No explanation at all

Comment: @benwiggy http://txt.do/1obke

Im starting to backup my files as well. Really dont wanna get jumped

Comment: Yeah, I'd say something's definitely screwy with your file system. Can you run `diskutil list` and provide the output?

Comment: @benwiggy https://gyazo.com/7a9f9f18748e7400aaad08c315b701c6

Comment: !!! No, I do not have another backup somewhere.!!! What?  You need to backup your important stuff ASAP. Get an external drive and a disk cloner like carbon copy cloner to make a complete copy of your system.  When you encrypt your drive you increase the risk of loosing all your data. backups are a must.  

!!

Comment: @historystamp i realize this . Im moving onto cloning my files and wiping my hard drive. Sad that this is an issue to begin with. 

When you say that i need to back up . I do have all my important files backed up of course. However its the random ones that i dont know i need that are not backed up

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there's no way of stopping the decryption process.

The error message you get indicate that either your file system is corrupt, or there's a bug in Apple's APFS implementation.

You can try downgrading and/or upgrading macOS (if a newer version is available). This might fix the problem as you could possibly work around a possible bug.

Apart from that, the only other possible fix is to copy all your files to a different disk. Then you can format this drive from scratch, and copy your files back.

Comment: Hey. I spent the day with apple support and they basically gave me this same message as well. While i do think thats the next logical step its kinda sad that this case has happened. I do fear one thing though. I tried reinstalling via recovery and filevault diasbled that. SO if i do format my HDD will it give me the same issue?

Comment: After formatting the problem is gone. However it is theoretically possible that you might trigger the same bug again if you choose to disable FileVault after it has been enabled once again. It’s not an error I’ve seen other people complain about, so I think the risk of that happening is very small.